# How exactly the R.string.* constants are generated?

Tags: android, android-resources

I'd like to store the generated constants of R.string in a DB.

Are the constants generated (semi-) randomly and can change e.g. between versions? Or are they are built like `hashCode`, so their values remain unchanged as long as XML-file `<string/>` elements is not touched?

Comment: Any time you add or remove resources, you can get completely different `R` values. Using those outside of a currently-running process is highly inadvisable.

Comment: this is what I was affraid of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't store `R.java` constants in a database, as their values can change when the application is recompiled.

Consider creating a `Map<Integer, String>` of some sort instead, where the keys are integer `R.string` IDs and the values are `String` constants. As long as each `String` constant corresponds to a unique `R.string` ID and their values never change, you can store them in the database instead.

Comment: Try it yourself and you'll see that the values of the resources can change. For example, build your app, save a copy of the local `R.java` build file (it's located in `app/build/generated/source/r/...`), then add a couple new resource strings, and then compare the old `R.java` to the new one.

Comment: I modified my answer to suggest a simple and safe workaround that you can use to get around this problem instead.

Comment: yeah, I'm going to store the strings in the db, and use reflection to get the actual xml values